# Pseudocode Python Concepts

Tags: python, pseudocode

I know that pseudocode by its very nature is based more on natural language syntax and principles than anything else, but it is supposed to represent coding concepts. I am still a beginner , so I don't understand all of the concepts.

```
    int string (char s[1..m], char t[1..n])
   // d is a table with m+1 rows and n+1 columns
   declare int d[0..m, 0..n]
```

I understand this except for the last line. Could somebody explain to this to me in python ?

Comment: It is defining a 2D integer array of size mxn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is declaring a 2D array of size mxn. With statically typed languages (and even with pseudocode), it's necessary/useful to state what the variable is before using it. If you've used C for example, we define variables before using them. With dynamic languages like Python, this is not necessary and you won't see it.

I guess the closest thing in Python would be like creating and empty list of lists holding integers and assigning it to `d`.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. I see that this got a lot of down-votes because it was probably not a good question for the site.

Comment: @PoetryLion I think it was especially if one is new to a different style of programming. It's not easy to map what you know from one class of languages to another..